# Is there a function that will allow me to prepend a string to the beginning of a set of lines within a text file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to prepend the IP addresses (in screenshot below) to the beginning of every line for their relative results.

[Text File showing current format of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzPyS.png)

**Current file format:**

```
Host: 192.168.1.4 ()    
21  open    tcp     ftp     vsftpd 2.3.4    
23  open    tcp     telnet      Linux telnetd   
25  open    tcp     smtp        Postfix smtpd   
53  open    tcp     domain      ISC BIND 9.4.2    
Host: 192.168.1.6 ()    
21  open    tcp     ftp     Microsoft ftpd  
25  open    tcp     smtp        Microsoft ESMTP 6.0.2600.2180   
80  open    tcp     http        Microsoft IIS httpd 5.1 
135 open    tcp     msrpc       Microsoft Windows RPC   
139 open    tcp     netbios-ssn     Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn
```

I have managed to append the first IP address to the beginning of every line using the following:

```
awk 'NR==1{IP="IP" FS $2 FS}NR!=1{$0=IP $0;print}' IPadd.txt > new.txt
```

Is there any way to modify this function so that I can have the different IP's at the beginning of each line and generate a file like this:

**I want the new text file to read:**

```
192.168.1.4 21  open    tcp     ftp     vsftpd 2.3.4    
192.168.1.4 23  open    tcp     telnet      Linux telnetd   
192.168.1.4 25  open    tcp     smtp        Postfix smtpd   
192.168.1.4 53  open    tcp     domain      ISC BIND 9.4.2
192.168.1.6 21  open    tcp     ftp     Microsoft ftpd  
192.168.1.6 25  open    tcp     smtp        Microsoft ESMTP 6.0.2600.2180   
192.168.1.6 80  open    tcp     http        Microsoft IIS httpd 5.1 
192.168.1.6 135 open    tcp     msrpc       Microsoft Windows RPC   
192.168.1.6 139 open    tcp     netbios-ssn     Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is "prepend"; "append" is specific to adding something *to the end* of something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^Host:/{ip=$2;next} NF{print ip,$0}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
192.168.1.4 21  open    tcp     ftp     vsftpd 2.3.4    
192.168.1.4 23  open    tcp     telnet      Linux telnetd   
192.168.1.4 25  open    tcp     smtp        Postfix smtpd   
192.168.1.4 53  open    tcp     domain      ISC BIND 9.4.2
192.168.1.6 21  open    tcp     ftp     Microsoft ftpd  
192.168.1.6 25  open    tcp     smtp        Microsoft ESMTP 6.0.2600.2180   
192.168.1.6 80  open    tcp     http        Microsoft IIS httpd 5.1 
192.168.1.6 135 open    tcp     msrpc       Microsoft Windows RPC   
192.168.1.6 139 open    tcp     netbios-ssn     Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn
```

Comment: You're a genius :-)

Comment: @jas, :) i believe it is you since, you posted nice code too buddy :)

Comment: What is the point of `NF`? There is no empty lines in OP's example

Comment: @oguzismail, I am pretty sure OP has edited that null line,when I ran it first time on my system it was printing 1 line with only IP(my memory is good :) ) so to avoid that I did that,later he/she would have removed it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I made a mistake while entering the code, There are actually **no** empty lines in the text file that I wish to prepend.

Comment: @Conjmcdaid94, no issues, even that is not there, an extra check shouldn't harm, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Host/h;//d;G;s/\(.*\)\nHost: \(.*\) ()/\2 \1/' file
```

Make a copy of the current Host line and append it to non-host lines, manipulating the host line to just present the ip address.